# Angular 2 HTTP only want JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using the angular2 HTTP module to get data from the SoundCloud API. I know how to get the data with observables:

```
   return this._http.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/users/${FEAT_USER_ID}/favorites?${CLIENT_ID_PARAM}`)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
```

How can I get this to JUST return the JSON object without using observables/having to subscribe to get data?

Comment: When you say "without using observables", what do you want it to return instead, given that it is an asynchronous operation? A promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

and then

```
 return this.http.get(this.publishersUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data) 
               .catch(this.handleError);
```

do read [the link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html), section: **Fall back to promises**

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. I'm able to extract the data and assign it to a variable using .then(). But when I call that variable outside of the then() it shows as undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: A network call is _asynchronous_, meaning it gets resolved at some unknown point in the future after the request is made. When that point in time is reached, the code in the functions passed to `.then()` runs and you can access the returned value. Any code outside such functions will actually run long before `.then()`, which is why the variable doesn't have a value yet. It's like asking "Why is this blank file labelled "My Death Certificate" in my filing cabinet empty?". :-)

Comment: Ahaha love the analogy. Thank you, Greg! Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service for example look at my user service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
import {User} from "./user";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {


  headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken(),
  });

  serverUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/api";

  constructor(private http:Http, private authService: AuthService) {



  }


  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any>{

    let url = this.serverUrl + "/accounts/login?include=user";

    return this.http.post(url, {username: username, password: password}, {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {

      return Observable.throw(err);
    })
  }

  register(user: User): Observable<any>{
    let url = this.serverUrl + "/accounts";
    this.headers.delete('Authorization');

    return this.http.post(url, user, {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {

      return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }

  logout(): Observable<any>{

    let url = this.serverUrl + '/accounts/logout';
    let data = {accessTokenID: this.authService.getToken()};
    return this.http.post(url, data, {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {
     return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }

}
```

now in component you can call

```
this.userService.login(user.username, user.password).subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response);


    }, err => {

      console.log(err);
    })
```

see the code on github: https://github.com/tabvn/angular-blog
Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFpwxTdy9gQ&list=PLFaW_8zE4amNEdKZOJD3P_GeV3Hgva7RD